# Option menu in Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android

Is it possible to force Samsung Galaxy S3 to have a fixed possition of the option menu in the top right corner of the screen as it is in other popular phones? In Samsung Galaxy S3 option menu is available only under the menu button. I would like to place a built-in help in the app in a fixed place in all types of devices.

I'm not sure if similar problem appears in other types of phones/tablets.

Comment: Create your own custom option menu, wherever you want just set it and use it.

Comment: you want to forcely show your option menu as overflow menu(as with icon of 3 dots)..?

Comment: yes exactly, I need to have the icon of 3 dots in the top right corner of the screen

Comment: @Annabelle ya then put one image with 3 dots and on the click on it, open one PopupWindow attached to 3 dots, that's it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this block of code in your activity which contains option Menu.

```
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(BaseActivity.this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
            .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if (menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

by this block use can access option menues from top right corner of action bar.
 even on Samsung Galaxy S3 when you click menu button, then option menu will open from action bar top right corner.
try using following menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Home"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logs"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="Logs"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/support"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        android:title="Support"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:orderInCategory="5"
        android:title="Logout"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for :)

Comment: this is "The" solution!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. in your activity:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_whatever:
// do your thing here
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

in /res/menu/main.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_whatever"
        android:title="@string/action_text"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_overflow"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
```